# Code First Entity Framework 6 rebuild project triggers context change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have set up a solution which contains a number of projects, including one for my models and one for the database contexts (and associated migrations).  I have two contexts - one for my standard database (ContextA) and one for the ASP.NET Identity tables (ContextB).  (I couldn't work out how to get these to "merge" into my existing context, but they do both point to the same DB).

Every single time I rebuild any project in my solution, I get the error "model backing the 'ContextA' context has changed since the database was created", and I have to do an update-database for EITHER context in order to continue.

I have found that I don't need to do an add-migration at all (and doing so for either context results in empty Up() and Down() methods).

Can anyone tell me what would be triggering the context to thing the model has changed?

Should I consider just adding Update-Database to the build script?

Comment: you have 2 db context, why don't you just merge both of them?

Comment: @YuliamChandra - "I couldn't work out how to get these to "merge" into my existing context, but they do both point to the same DB" was in the very first paragraph.

Comment: Not sure why you can't merge both of them, you only need to merge the DbSet collections in a single db context, take a look [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VdkTMZ).

Answer (score 0):

The migrationhistory table in your database is usually associated with one context which then compares against your models to keep everything in sync.  I can see why you get this odd behavior.  I have two contexts per application instance but I also have two databases.

I recommend you merge your context and models or split them into different databases (which ever makes sense in your app design).  This will resolve your issue.